Does such a weird convergent sequence exist?
Let $X$ be the Banach space of all $L^1$ functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Take a convergent sequence $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ of functions from $X$. Let's call a sequence $g_1,g_2,\ldots$ of functions from $X$ a straightening of sequence $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ iff:

for each $n\geq1$ there exists $t_n$ such that $g_n(x)=f_n(x+t_n)$, and
for each $n>1$, this $t_n$ is chosen so that $g_n$ and $g_{n-1}$ are as close to each other as possible, i.e.
$$\int_\mathbb{R}|g_{n-1}(x)-g_n(x)|dx=\min_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\int_\mathbb{R}|g_{n-1}(x)-f_n(x+t)|dx.$$

My question is: Is there a convergent sequence in $X$ such that all or at least some (these are the two variants of the question) of its straightenings are non-convergent?

I've been trying to get $t_n - t_{n-1} = 1/n$ without much success in the hopes that $g_n$ would stop being pointwise convergent. Do you know some family of functions for which $t_n$ is easy to compute?

@Radost I think I actually do. Approximately at least, that is. Take a look at this construction: $f_n(x)=e^{-x^2}+a_ne^{-bx^2}cos(cx+d_n)$. Here, $b$ and $c$ are constants, about $\frac{1}{100}$ and $100$ in size, respectively; $d_n$ grows steadily, linearly, about $d_n=\frac{n}{30}$, and $a_n$ converges to $0$ very slowly, about $a_n=\frac{1}{10}e^{-\frac{n}{100}}$.

CORRECTION: $d_n$ is about $n$, not $\frac{n}{30}$.
